# How to input tail -1 into sh script var

Tags: linux, bash, shell

AIM: I would like to tail the last line of the file.txt and input into a variable to use for substitution via sed.

CODE:

```
 ALARM_POPUP_CONTENT=(tail -1 /logs/file.txt)
 ALARM_POPUP_CONTENT=tail -1 /logs/file.txt
```

OUTCOME:

This is only outputtin the work 'tail' or an error command not found for the seond option. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
ALARM_POPUP_CONTENT=$(tail -1 /logs/file.txt)
```

or with backticks:

```
ALARM_POPUP_CONTENT=`tail -1 /logs/file.txt`
```